# How to assign custom id tags to html tags while looping through foreach statement in razor mvc

Tags: jquery, html, razor

In my cshtml view, If I have:

```
 foreach (var x in mycollection)
  { 

      <li id="a + @x.id"></li>


   }
```

If you look how i'm setting this id, I'm assigning 'a' plus the id so a1, or a2, or a3, ect...to give each element separate id's. Hoever this isn't working for me when I go to use it in jquery:

```
     function(id) {
       $('#a' + id).css({ "visibility": "hidden" });
      }
```

I can't just use '@x.Id' because I'm already using that somewhere else. How can I make these id's custom? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `<li id="a + @x.id"></li>` should be `<li id="a-@x.id"></li>` and then `$('#a-' + id)`.

Because `<li id="a + @x.id"></li>` creates a element like `<li id="a + 1"></li>` not `<li id="a1"></li>`